# How to select checkboxes using RSelenium?

Tags: r, rselenium

I'm trying to use RSelenium to select checkboxes. The website is [here](https://www.kap.org.tr/en/bildirim-sorgu).

As I can see there are 2 solutions.

- If I choose to click checkboxes then the class is changing as from 'w-clearfix notifications-row' to 'w-clearfix notifications-row selected'.
- If I choose to click numbers then I can get class is vcell.

What my aim is to select all of the checkboxes and use clickElement() function.

The rest of the code is:

```
driver <- rsDriver(browser = "chrome", port = 80L, chromever = "83.0.4103.39")
rmDr <- driver[["client"]]
rmDr$navigate("https://www.kap.org.tr/en/bildirim-sorgu")

showMe <- rmDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', "//*/a[@class = 'filter-button4 first']")
showMe$clickElement()

selectAll <- rmDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', "//*/div[@class = '???']")
selectAll$clickElement()
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a loop to select all checkboxes:

```
library(RSelenium)
driver <- rsDriver(browser = "chrome", port = 80L, chromever = "83.0.4103.39")
rmDr <- driver[["client"]]
rmDr$navigate("https://www.kap.org.tr/en/bildirim-sorgu")

showMe <- rmDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', "//*/a[@class = 'filter-button4 first']")
showMe$clickElement()

for(i in 4:43) {
  selectAll <- rmDr$findElement(using = 'css', paste("#tab1 > div > div:nth-child(2) > div.w-container.visible > div > div:nth-child(",i,") > a", sep = ""))
  selectAll$clickElement()
  Sys.sleep(1)
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Dominik ! So, how can I find out how many boxes there are? for() loop should be dynamic.

Comment: You could first scrape the "50 notification found" part (top right of table) and then use that number in the for loop